# Theorem number subsection

Tags: cross-referencing, numbering, newtheorem

There are 3 chapters in my paper. In the 1st chapter, there are three sections.
 In my first section there are eight subsections. I want the Theorem and Definition numbers as following; like Theorem 1.2.4 or Definition 1.8.1, etc.

In the remaining 2 sections there are no subsections. In the second section I want it shows like this: Theorem 2.1 or Definition 2.4, etc that is without subsection number.
In the third section, I want it to be Definition 3.1,etc.

I tried to edit `\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[subsection]` and met with some troubles, in the eighth subsection of  section 1, the last number is 1.1.8.8. In section 2, the number of the first definition is 1.2.0.9. How to edit the code to make the number 1.2.0.9 be 1.2.1?

Please suggest the suitable commands.

Comment: So you want the theorems to be numbered as "chapter.section.subsection", without any number referencing to the theorem itself? Or as "section.subsection.theorem"?

Comment: what about others chapters?

Comment: Why is this tagged with `biblatex` and `bibtex`? Not related to the question

Comment: I removed the tags `biblatex` and `bibtex`, which are about bibliographies (and are *usually* understood as rivalling systems - though they need not be if one interprets the tags more generally) and don't seem to apply here. I also removed the `winedt` tag since the question does not mention the editor explicitly and this appears to be an editor-independent question. If any of the removed tags were important, please add them back and explain in the question body why they are important.

Comment: @Vincent，numbered as chapter section subsection

Comment: So if you have two theorems in chapter 1, section 1, subsection 8, both will have number `1.1.8`? Or do you want `1.1.8,1` for the first and `1.1.8.2` for the second?

Comment: @egreg， I want 1.1.8.1 and 1.1.8.2

Comment: I think just issuing `\numberwithin{thm}{subsection}` before a subsection in which you want equations to be numbered by subsection, and `\numberwithin{thm}{section}` before a section in which you want equations to be numbered by section, should do the job.

Answer (score 1):

Don't. But if you really insist,

```
\documentclass[oneside]{book} % oneside to make a smaller picture
\usepackage[a5paper]{geometry} % just to make a smaller picture
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[subsection]
\renewcommand{\thethm}{%
  \ifnum\value{subsection}>0
    \thesubsection
  \else
    \thesection
  \fi
  .\arabic{thm}%
}

\begin{document}

\chapter{First chapter}

\section{First section}

\subsection{First subsection}

\begin{thm}
First theorem
\end{thm}

\subsection{Second subsection}

\begin{thm}
Second theorem
\end{thm}

\begin{thm}
Third theorem
\end{thm}

\section{Second section}

\subsection{Third subsection}

\begin{thm}
Fourth theorem
\end{thm}

\chapter{Second chapter}

\section{Third section}

\begin{thm}
Fifth theorem
\end{thm}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The following redefinition of `\thethm` should meet your requirements. If you want definitions to be numbered in a similar way, and if you have defined for example `\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}`, then a similar redefinition of `\thedefinition` should work.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}
\renewcommand{\thethm}{%
    \ifnum \value{subsection} = 0
        \arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}%
    \else
        \arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}%
    \fi%
}
\begin{document}
\chapter{First chapter}
\section{A section with subsections}
\subsection{A subsection}
\begin{thm}
A theorem.
\end{thm}
\subsection{Another subsection}
\begin{thm}
Another theorem.
\end{thm}
\section{Another section with subsections}
\subsection{A subsection}
\begin{thm}
A theorem.
\end{thm}
\chapter{Second chapter}
\section{A section without subsections}
\begin{thm}
A theorem.
\end{thm}
\section{Another one}
\begin{thm}
Another theorem.
\end{thm}
\end{document}
```

This example produces the following two first chapters:
[image]

[image]

Comment: I think you mean `\renewcommand{\thethm}{%
    \ifnum \value{subsection} = 0
        \arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}%
    \else
        \arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}%
    \fi.\arabic{thm}
}`

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, the OP just wants the theorems numbered as chapter.section.subsection (when subsections are used), without reference to the theorem itself.

Comment: The question is not clear indeed, that's why i ask what about other chapters? From `Theorem 1.2.4 or Definition 1.8.1` i guess  1 is section's number 8 is the subsection number and 1 theorem number but ...